# Rotate instances to align with normals

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: geometry]
[image: nodes]

Can anyone tell me how to get the pyramids to align with the normals of the deformed plane? I am using mesh to points so that I can target vertices, edges and faces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do it with this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

UPDATE:

with your blend file, i could figure it out:

You inserted mesh to point nodes, which stop it from working, if you mute them, you get:

[image]

*** UPDATE ****

i found a better solution:

this node setup:

[image]

gets this result:

[image]

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, whilst this does indeed rotate the instances. In my example i'm targetting individual mesh components and I cannot see how to use your method with the mesh to points node. I've tried it with capture attribute also, just doesn't seem to have normal data.

Comment: Hi Neil, if you provide your blend file, I will help you. But without it I can only guess around.

Comment: that's very kind of you - https://pasteall.org/blend/ec19ac9c2baa4a868284ad1bb03e56b5

Comment: delete or mute your mesh to points nodes...then it works, i updated my answer

Comment: if I mute the mesh to points nodes, I will no longer have instances on faces and lines though

Comment: @Neil: i found a better solution. I update my answer. Hope you are happy now ;)